# Which package of Visual Studio 2013 ISO contains the devenv.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am having issues with Visual Studio 2013 Installation. Uninstall and reinstall fails to resolve. Its now saying its installed but devenv.exe and its dependencies are not there in Common7\Ide\ folder. Hence it does not run and Lightswitch and Webtoolsextensionsvs2013 do not get installed even after a repair.
I have resolved to manually install the missing stuff hence I need to know which package contains devenv.exe. 
Please help?

Comment: What do you think the odds are that certain files are missing but that e.g. all of the registry information is going to be absolutely correct?

Comment: I will install in identically structured virtual machine. then copy the visualstudio\12.0 branch from registry

Comment: After that a repair should fix things